# how to set a domain name for an iis hosed application which is mapped to a public ip

Tags: asp.net, iis, domain-name

i have an application hosted on iis in one of the local system and it is mapped with public ip. Up to now we are using this by  http://public-ip/application/login.aspx   it is working perfectly, now we want to assign a domain name for the above url and have to access with that domain name from the outside also. can some one suggest what i have to do further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few steps:

1. Buy the domain from any domain registrar. I personally use namcheap.com but you can use anyone you like.
2. Make sure you also purchase (if not included) the DNS management service (also called nameservers).
3. Once domain is purchased, login to your control panel and modify the DNS record.
4. Add an `A Record` for your domain, like this, where your IP is `111.111.111.111`:

   ```
   yourdomain.com.   IN A 111.111.111.111
   ```
5. (Optional) you may want to add a `CNAME` record (an alias) so that `www.yourdomain.com` also works; that record would look like this:

   ```
   www             CNAME   yourdomain.com.
   ```
6. Go to IIS, and change the name of the site to the domain name.
7. Wait for 30 - 40 minutes for the global DNS servers to propagate the changes.
8. Enjoy your new site.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. if we already have domain  so called example.com, i want to append my appname to that domain called appname.example.com by editing the A record with the public ip. Is it works. sorry for the typo or grammar mistakes